# Is it possible to retrieve commit from git reflog

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to recover git commit from data that is received from `git reflog` ?

Example of the `git reflog` output.

```
eff9143 HEAD@{14}: merge develop: Fast-forward
e3ad8f7 HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from develop to master
eff9143 HEAD@{16}: commit: Add Login view. Setting up project structure.
e3ad8f7 HEAD@{17}: checkout: moving from master to develop
e3ad8f7 HEAD@{18}: commit: Add LaunchScreen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

Read all about it here:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716)

What you can do is to create new branch or reset the current branch to your desired commit and than work on it.

```
# create new branch 
git checkout -b <name> <sha-1>

# "move" the current branch to any given commit
git reset HEAD --hard
```

and again all is described in details in the above answer.